# Deployment and Hosting a Angular Frontend and Go Backend

Tags: angular, firebase, google-app-engine, go, deployment

I am new to web deployment and hosting but have been coding for a couple years

I currently have a backend and frontend that work separately. I was able to deploy the frontend in Firebase and have the backend containerized (Docker) then running in Google Compute Engine (GCE) and deployed on Google App Engine (GAE) with a flex environment. Both are working independently and wonderfully; locally and in their respected deployed services but now I want to have it work under my custom domain I bought from Google Domains, let it be sicko-project.com

Locally i have my backend as `local:8080/api/ping` and my frontend `localhost:4200/ping` which gets the backend data  from `localhost:8080/api/ping`

My question is how can I have them work under my domain?

What I know.

I know that you can't have two separate web servers under one domain, I embarrassingly learned that by chatting with Google support chat as well as common sense. Tunnel vision is great!

I know that I can have both in different subdomains: frontend on `www.app.sicko-project.com` and `www.api.sicko-project.com`

How can I have my website be `www.sicko-project.com/ping` similar to how i use it locally.

Thanks

Also I am using MongoDB for the database

**EDIT:**
I got thinking will i have to redirect traffic in code to sicko-project.com
and get my backend and frontend talk by:

*--pseudo-ish code--*

backend code having somethinglike group(app.sicko-project.com/api/ping)
and frontend code have get(api.sicko-project.com/api/ping)

**EDIT2:**
add some cors middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure both services under the same domain using sub domains.

this means you can have `app.sicko-project.com` or even the naked domain `sicko-project.com` for the front end and `api.sicko-project.com` for the back end.

To configure the front end in **Firebase** to the custom domain you can follow [This Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?hl=en) which has the following steps:

- Add the domain

  - [here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/hosting/main) enter the wizard to connect a domain, and follow it.
  - This will require a validation process which takes some time
- Verify domain ownership

  - On your registrar go to the DNS management page
  - Add a new record
  - Wait for it to be propagated

For the Back End in **App Engine** you can follow [This Guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/mapping-custom-domains?hl=en) which explains the following steps:

- Verify Ownership of the domain [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home)
- Go to App Engine >> Settings >> Custom Domain
- Select Add Custom Domain
- Select the one you want to use
- Point it to the service you want
- Update your DNS Records with the CNAME registry you get.

Comment: Okay yeah I understand that portion sorry for the confusing question my question is how can I get data from my api.sicko-project.com  to my frontend from sicko-project.com so my data can appear?

Comment: So is your question How the front end could call the back end when using the custom domains? if that is your question then the answer is enabling CORS and making the calls to the full path

Comment: I guess it is a little of both but mainly the latter. So the landing page is www.sicko-project.com and then navigate to www.sick-project.com/ping. Under the hood it would be api.sicko-project.com is being called to get data from app.sicko-project.com. This done by enabling cors and when you say full path it means something similar to: (in frontend code) get(api.sicko-project.com/api/ping)

Comment: should i add the sicko-project.com base domain to the GAE (backend) or just api.sicko-project.com.

Comment: just the subdomain you are going to use